# Cookie/session problems on login frontend and admin

Tags: login, session, cookie

I have an issue with login in admin and frontend for accounts. This started in Safari only.

Not being a developer I'm not sure how to look to see what the cookie is trying to do, as I don't ever use Mozilla I tried and got in OK but can't on IE or chrome.

I have set the session in admin and that cured the Safari issue up until a few days ago, now I get the issue with the looping, if you put an incorrect password in it tells you so I know it does work as it should but I just can't login.

I think this is a session issue but not sure what could cause this. If anyone can see what the error is, I'd very much appreciate some feedback.

Comment: im not 100% sure what your issue is, but I'd try clearing cookies in chrome and IE

Comment: its related to cookies..

Comment: I tried clearing cookies, its like something decided it was no longer going to work, it lets you in when you clear the cookies, what im trying to work out is why you would need to clear the cookies and previously you did not, in safari it wont let customers into front end ive tried looking at safari errors but cant see what the issue is

Comment: What are your cookie settings of Magento? You said you've changed something in admin, what did you do?

Comment: cookie lifetime 96000, cookie path / cookie domain .mfeuk.co.uk use http only set to no and cookie restriction mode set to no,